# Trouble with form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a simple form with JavaScript but cannot get the script to validate. When the Submit button is pressed there is no validation being run. If one of the boxes is left blank, the error message does not pop up to notify the user. However I am not seeing anything out of place.  I am wondering if it isthe submit button is not working? Can anyone lend a hand?

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD  XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>LASTNAME: Warner Form Validation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function btnSubmit_onclick() {
     var myForm = document.formContact;
     if(myForm.txtAge.value == "" || myForm.txtName.value == "") {
        alert.("Please complete all of the fields.");
        if(myForm.txtName.vale == ""){
           myForm.txtName.focus();
        } else {
           myForm.txtAge.focus();
     } else{
        alert("Thank you for completing the form"+myForm.txtName.value);
     }
  }
  function txtAge_onblur() {
     var txtAge = document.formContact.txtAge;
     if(isNaN(txtAge.value) == true) {
        alert("Please Enter a Valid Age");
        txtAge.select();
    }
  function txtName_onchange(); {
     window.status = "Hi" + document.form1.txtName.value;
     docment.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Hi" + document.frm1.txtName.value;
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" id="formContact" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" name="formContact">
     <p>Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="theName"><span class="err" id="nameErr"></span>
     </p>
     <p>Age:<br />
        <input type="text" name="theAge"><span class="err" id="ageErr"></span>
     </p>
     <p>
     <p>How may we contact you?<br>
        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">Email<br>
        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="no contact">No Contact<br>
     </p>
     <p><input type="button" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit" onclick="btnSubmit_onclick></p>
  </form>
  <span id="results"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the name of the function.

Comment: Put that as an answer

Comment: you got literally 10 typos there. Your code never gets executed.

Comment: onclick="btnSubmit_onclick()"

Comment: add closing } to btnSubmit_onclck and in onClick use btnSubmit_onclick()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had SO many typo's. This works.

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD  XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>LASTNAME: Warner Form Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function btnSubmit_onclick() {
 var myForm = document.formContact;
 if(myForm.txtAge.value == "" || myForm.txtName.value == "") {
    alert("Please complete all of the fields.");
    if(myForm.txtName.vale == ""){
       myForm.txtName.focus();
    } else {
       myForm.txtAge.focus();
    }
 } else{
    alert("Thank you for completing the form"+myForm.txtName.value);
 }
}
function txtAge_onblur() {
 var txtAge = document.formContact.txtAge;
 if(isNaN(txtAge.value) == true) {
    alert("Please Enter a Valid Age");
    txtAge.select();
}
function txtName_onchange() {
 window.status = "Hi" + document.form1.txtName.value;
 docment.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = "Hi" + document.frm1.txtName.value;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="formContact" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();" name="formContact">
 <p>Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="txtName"><span class="err" id="nameErr"></span>
 </p>
 <p>Age:<br />
    <input type="text" name="txtAge"><span class="err" id="ageErr"></span>
 </p>
 <p>
 <p>How may we contact you?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">Email<br>
    <input type="radio" name="contact" value="no contact">No Contact<br>
 </p>
 <p><input type="button" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit" onclick="btnSubmit_onclick()"></p>
</form>
<span id="results"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

However be noted that you haven't used txtAge_onBlur or txtName_onChange functions anywhere. Also I suggest to add a numerical check to age field.

Answer (score 0):

You have `onsubmit="return validate();"` yet I don't see `validate()` anywhere in your script.

Then in your script you have `btnSubmit_onclck()`, yet in your HTML you have `onclick="btnSubmit_onclick`.

So it's missing an `i` and in the HTML you are missing the closing `"`.

You also need to check the missing closing `}` on `txtAge_onblur` and `btnSubmit_onclick`

Comment: before that even happens the function in the submit onclick is spelled wrong too

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="btnSubmit_onclick></p>
```

to

```
onclick="btnSubmit_onclick();"></p>
```

and

```
function btnSubmit_onclck() {
```

to

```
function btnSubmit_onclick() {
```